# Why functional programming over c

Tags: c, functional-programming

How is functional programming useful over normal procedural languages like c or object oriented programming languages like c++ and where does it shine?

Comment: Just type in ["functional programming"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=functional+programming) in the search field of StackOverflow and you will get a big amount of information and disambiguation.

Answer (score 3):

C lacks several features of functional programming that need to be worked around (likewise, while you can write in an object-oriented style in C, you need to work around several missing features as well).

C functions are not first-class objects. You cannot return a function from a function, store a function in a variable, or pass a function to another function. You cannot nest functions, and you cannot create anonymous functions. The workaround is that C does allow you to use pointers to functions, so you can write a function that takes a pointer to a function as an argument, but this is not as clean as what you can do in a language oriented towards functional programming.

C lacks closures, which are a way of capturing the “environment” of execution at a particular point in a program (namely, what variable names are bound to).

C lacks generics, except in the most broad sense. In most functional languages, it is possible to write one function which applies to a large number of different types because they don’t depend on specific attributes of those types.

Answer (score -5):

C is a low level language giving the programmer the full control over the program execution. It was newer designed to thigh level abstract language.

Functional programming is not popular and most languages used nowadays are object oriented.

If you need the language which gives you ability to control the program and the environment you should consider C++

Comment: What language does not give you control over the program and environment?